# append(variable) inserts wrong value, i am at loss

Tags: python, append

```
def primesFaster(to_number):
array = [x for x in range(2, to_number + 1)]
result = list()
i = array[0]
while(i*i < to_number):
    result.append(array[i])      #<<----- i = 2 in debugger but still appends 4
    for x in array:
        if(x%i == 0): array.remove(x)
    i = array[0]
result.extend(array)
return result
```

--

```
 result.append(array[i])
```

Should append 2,3,5... values to result array but for some reason it appends 4 in the first loop iteration how can it happen ? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `array[0]` is 2 and `array[2]` is 4.

```
array = [x for x in range(2, to_number + 1)]  # [2, 3, 4, ..., to_number]
```

You basically call

```
result.append(array[array[0]])
```

Comment: oh my god thanks i should get some rest instead of trying to learn late friday i guess

Comment: @newUser haha you're welcome :D we all have or had to learn late friday at some point